# Root version of ruby not installing in terminal even though rbenv is updated

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I'm trying to update my root version of ruby. It seems like the root directory isn't updating. Even with installing ruby through homebrew or with rbenv - ruby will update but running ruby -v continues to stay at version 2.6. I'm concerned the main root is wrong and I'm wondering how to fix this.

Running this command gets the following output:

ruby -v

ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958)
[universal.arm64e-darwin23]

Running this command gets the following output:

rbenv version:

3.3.0 (set by /Users/ninajay/.ruby-version)

Running this command gets the following output:

export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"

ruby -v

ruby 3.3.0 (2023-12-25 revision 5124f9ac75) [arm64-darwin23]

ALSO when I run this, the following is my path:

env | grep PATH

PATH=/Users/ninajay/opt/miniconda3/bin:/Users/ninajay/opt/miniconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools

Comment: Did you run `rbenv init`? I don't see it in your PATH anywhere, although the [Docs](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv?tab=readme-ov-file#how-rbenv-hooks-into-your-shell) suggest it should be there.

Comment: I did but when I ran these commands: 

rbenv init
# Load rbenv automatically by appending
# the following to ~/.zshrc:

eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"

(base) ninajay@Ninas-MBP-2 ~ % ~/.zshrc

it said this:
zsh: permission denied: /Users/ninajay/.zshrc

do you know how to fix this?

Comment: .zshrc is a text file. Open it and paste into it what the instructions say to append.

Comment: I tried to do that and then messed it up and accidently deleted the .zshrc file and instead of saying permissions denied it says file doesn't exist - do you have any tips? i know this was a dumb error

Comment: You can create it again. Any user on your system should get one by default if you create using the "skeleton" example, and the location of these templates can be found in your distribution documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to update your "root" version of Ruby.

Since you're on Mac, you have a preinstalled version of Ruby at the path `/usr/bin/ruby`. If anything, this is your "root" version of Ruby. The only good way to update this is to update macOS and hope Apple updated Ruby for you.

If you install Ruby via homebrew or rbenv or rvm or whatever, it is a completely separate Ruby installation. For example it might be in `/opt/homebrew/bin/ruby` or `~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/ruby`.

The question is: when you type `ruby` in your shell, which one do you want it to run and what is the best way to get it to do that?

First, you want to be running the rbenv version. The whole point of rbenv is that it lets you easily update ruby whenever you want and switch versions at will. That means you want `ruby` to run `~/.rbenv/shims/ruby`. You can manually check if rbenv installed the version you want by running this directly:

```
~/.rbenv/shims/ruby -v
```

Now what is the best way to make `ruby` run that version? Read the [instructions for your shell](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) under "Configure your shell to load rbenv". This *usually* involves adding a line like `eval "$(~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv init - bash)"` to your shell config, but it depends on which specific shell you are using. Again, you can test this manually by running

```
rbenv init
ruby -v
```

If running `ruby` ever does something you don't expect you can also run `type -a ruby` to see all the possible things your shell could run (in priority order). This can help you debug if something is misconfigured to run the wrong thing.